# Deleting Elements of a file in vc++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

```
CStringArray myArray;
myArray.copy(copiedsomeelements);
CString file1="myfile1";
CString file2="myfile2";
FILE *fp1,*fp2;
CString linetocompare="mytext";
fp1 = fopen(myfile1, "rb");
fread(data, 1280, 1, fp1);
fclose(fp1);
TCHAR * pch = _tcstok(data, _T("\r\n"));


fp2 = fopen(myfile2, "w"); //open new file

for (int m = 0; m < myArray.GetCount(); m++)
{
        CString temp(pch);
        if (strcmp(myArray.GetAt(m), linetocompare) != NULL)
        {
                fprintf(fp2, "%s", temp); 
                fwrite("\r\n", 1, 1, fp2);
        }
        pch = _tcstok(NULL, _T("\r\n"));
}
fclose(fp2);
remove(myfile1); //remove old file
rename(myfile2, myfile1);
```

The above code that works fine for me but not all the time. Sometimes it writes the "myfile2" as it is without comparing "linetocomapare" element.
Please help me with this.
Let me know if any clarifications are required. Thank you.

Comment: You are reading arbitrary chunks of data. Those need not contain a full `"\r\n"` sequence, for example, nor is there any guarantee, that your search item does not straddle consecutive blocks. And since this question is tagged [tag:c++], you should be using C++. That is: [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). There are lots more bugs in this piece of code, though. Please consult your introductory books.

Comment: Thank you for helping me to improve.

Answer (score 2):

MFC has a [CStdioFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstdiofile-class) class that wraps the narly FILE stuff and can handle line feeds. Here's a couple of convenience functions for loading/saving text files:

```
void ReadTextFileContents(CString const& filePath,
    CArray<CString>& lines,
    UINT openFlags = CFile::modeRead | CFile::shareDenyWrite)
{
    CStdioFile file(filePath, openFlags);

    try
    {
        CString line;
        while (file.ReadString(line))
            lines.Add(line);
        file.Close();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        file.Abort();
        throw;
    }
}

void WriteTextFileContents(CString const& filePath,
    CArray<CString> const& lines,
    UINT openFlags = CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeWrite |
    CFile::shareExclusive)
{
    CStdioFile file(filePath, openFlags);

    try
    {
        for (INT_PTR i = 0, count = lines.GetCount(); i < count; ++i)
        {
            file.WriteString(lines[i]);
            if (i < (count - 1))
            {
                // NOTE: The default mode for CStdioFile is text mode
                // MSDN: Text mode provides special processing for carriage
                // return-linefeed pairs. When you write a newline character
                // (0x0A) to a text-mode CStdioFile object, the byte pair
                // (0x0D, 0x0A) is sent to the file. When you read, the
                // byte pair (0x0D, 0x0A) is translated to a single 0x0A
                // byte.
                file.WriteString(_T("\n"));
            }
        }
        file.Close();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        file.Abort();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
    try
    {
        CArray<CString> lines;
        ReadTextFileContents(fileName, lines);

        // Do what you want with lines, remove items, copy to
        // another array, etc.

        // Now write them somewhere
        WriteTextFileContents(fileName2, lines);
    }
    catch (CException* ex)
    {
        // Grab and display error message here
        //ex->GetErrorMessage();

        ex->Delete();
    }
```